# Unable to get XPC to receive data from the client

Tags: swift, macos, xpc, mach

I'm trying to get a simple command-line Swift application that will be later used for native messaging with Chrome\Firefox to communicate with the other app of the workplace.

Main UI app (ie. the XPC server):

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//

import Cocoa
import IOKit.ps
import Foundation
import Dispatch

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.my.label");
        let conn:xpc_connection_t = xpc_connection_create_mach_service("com.test.xpc", queue, UInt64(XPC_CONNECTION_MACH_SERVICE_LISTENER));
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            xpc_connection_set_event_handler(conn) { [weak self] client in
                debugPrint("client", client);
                xpc_connection_set_event_handler(client) { [weak self] object in
                    debugPrint("server received message:", xpc_copy_description( object ));
                }
                xpc_connection_resume(client);
            }
            print("inside dispatch");
            xpc_connection_resume(conn);
        }
        debugPrint("here after listener")
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

The command-line app (ie. the XPC client)

```
//
//  main.swift
//

import Foundation
import XPC

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.my.queue");
let conn:xpc_connection_t = xpc_connection_create_mach_service("com.test.xpc", queue, 0);

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    xpc_connection_resume(conn);
}

var message:xpc_object_t  = xpc_dictionary_create(nil, nil, 0 );
xpc_dictionary_set_string( message, "message", "hello world" );

xpc_connection_send_message(conn, message);

debugPrint("Exiting")
```

When I run the command-line app, the server doesn't receive any message, so I'm guessing either the client app is not finding it or the server is not properly setup.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

UI:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.my.label");
```

CLI:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.my.queue");
```

Shouldn't you be using the same queue?

Answer (score 0):

Mach services cannot be registered on demand from code, they must be defined in the `MachServices` entry in the program's launchd property list. However, fundamentally I suspect you have a misconception about how XPC Mach Services work because almost always the command line tool will be the one acting as the server (although this is not a hard requirement).